# Perspective correction using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, homography

After bounding natural images with textboxes (green), I want to apply a homography matrix (perspective correction) to project the green area to a rectangle.

Please refer to the link for the image mentioned above

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhe4S.jpg

How can I implement the code / call the code in

> http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/26141-homography-matrix

Alternatively, any other possibilities of other suitable algorithms?

I can provide you with the coordinates of the bounding box, obtained with

```
img=imread('perspective.jpg');
imshow(img); ginput(4)
```

and the coordinates of the quadrangle is

```
ans =

   23.1597   25.0459
   22.0220   55.9541
  164.2375   61.6427
  165.3752   30.1657
```

Comment: Take a look at the bottom half of the duplicate post.  It shows you how to warp images from one set of points to another.

Comment: The older post talks about matching. However, I am doing pre-processing before OCR. I'm afraid I don't have "the original/model image" for the mapping.

Comment: That shouldn't matter.  The source points would be what you have for the quadrangle, and the target points should be the corner points of the output rectangle.  The underlying principle is the same.  You simply have to use `estimateGeometricTransform` given those two sets of points instead of images themselves.

Comment: Thanks everyone. My final implementation is to first crop the minimum rectangle that bounds the quadrangle (to facilitate calculations). Then calculate the width and height of it. The final image is projected onto a rectangle of (0,0) (w,0) (w,h) (0,h). This assumes a parallelogram. Works ok with ocr. Hopes to have better alogirthm for calculating w and h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the homography transformation between the two bounding boxes using the `fitgeotrans` function. You can then apply the resulting transformation to the image using `imwarp`.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. Sorry from a Matlab newbie. Can you write an example code?

Comment: @user2513881 - Type in `help fitgeotrans` in MATLAB and read the documentation.

Comment: I suppose moving points are the detected corners. But how about the stationary points?